# Extract time component from date in a dataset

Tags: date-and-time

I have a dataset of dates in the following format - Wed 18 Feb 1801 18:00. I want to extract only 18:00 from these dates i.e, the time component only. How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) with `{"Hour", ":", "Minute"}` as the second argument:

```
DateString[#, {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}] &["Wed 18 Feb 1801 18:00"]
```

> "18:00"

Comment: Thank you  for your reply. 
But I have trouble applying it to a column in the dataset. 
For example, I tried extracting the year component - DateObject[Data1[All, "SalesDate"] // Normal, "Year"], where SalesDate appears as Wed 18 Feb 1801. 
I am confused. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use [`TimeObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeObject)/[`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject), and then convert to a string if needed:

```
TimeObject @ DateObject @ "Wed 18 Feb 1801 18:00"
DateString @ %
```

> [image]
>
> "18:00"

Comment: Thank you  for your reply. 
But I have trouble applying it to a column in the dataset. 
For example, I tried extracting the year component - DateObject[Data1[All, "SalesDate"] // Normal, "Year"], where SalesDate appears as Wed 18 Feb 1801. 
I am confused. Please help